# IF loop with multiple OR condition throwing syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I want to add multiple or condition where I am comparing string values, with single string value my following code is working

```
 prname ="$projname"
    if prname == 'CheckForUpdate':
        settingsdata['autocompare'] = True
        settingsdata['autorecords'] = True
```

but when I am adding multiple OR condition it is throwing following syntax error:

```
prname ="$projname"
    if [prname == 'CheckForUpdate'] || [prname == 'Result'];
    then
            settingsdata['autocompare'] = True
            settingsdata['autorecords'] = True
```

ERROR getting:

```
 if [ prname == 'CheckForUpdate' ] || [ prname == 'Result' ]
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anybody know why is it so and I am using **#!/bin/sh**?

Comment: What language are you _intending_ to use? `sh`?  Python?

Comment: Using sh language

Comment: You should probably correct "my following code" in the question if the original program was written _by someone else_, who did not tell you what language it was written in, and explain that this is the case.

Comment: Are you sure you're working with a shell script and not a Python script? `sh` have no support for associative arrays (your `settingsdata` array).  Why have you tagged this with [tag:bash] if it's a `sh` script?  In any case, `sh` and `bash` scripts does not support assignments with spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many errors it is hard to know where to start if this is really supposed to be shell.

```
if prname == 'CheckForUpdate':
```

in shell will call a command `prname` with two arguments `==` and `CheckForUpdate:`
and so will probably give you an error saying it can't find a command named `prname`.

```
if [ prname == 'CheckForUpdate' ] || [ prname == 'Result' ]
```

is better, but it compares the string `prname` with the two strings `CheckForUpdate` and `Result` and so will always be false (neither CheckForUpdate nor Result starts with `p`).

```
settingsdata['autocompare'] = True
```

with the spaces around the `=` will be a syntax error in most shell implementations, it is **not** an assignment.

Comment: Of course, the more sensible thing to do, if one has a working Python script that one is clearly running via a Python interpreter (from which one is getting Python error messages when one gets Python syntax wrong), is to continue writing that script in Python.  Someone had to say this.  (-: